# ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'intrinsic gas too low'} how to resolve , see the code in body, looking for help

Tags: web3js, transactions, python, goerli

```
from web3 import Web3

infura_url = "https://goerli.infura.io/v3/<key>"
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))
account_1 = '0x0BD2c4B74c3DEcF804567eb91DF84F3fAcC6DE32'
private_key1 = 'Private Key'
account_2 = '0xD1ED7acB72F84134203BB25AA0F5395a876BE18c'

#get the nonce.  Prevents one from sending the transaction twice
nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account_1)
tx = {
    'nonce': nonce,
    'to': account_2,
    'value': web3.toWei(1, 'gwei'),
    'gas': 4000,
    'gasPrice': web3.toWei('0', 'gwei')
}
signed_tx = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, private_key1)


#sign the transaction
signed_tx = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, private_key1)

#send transaction
tx_hash = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)

#get transaction hash
print(web3.toHex(tx_hash))
```

---

after following chage i made in code , it worked. thanks you support.

```
tx = {
    'nonce': nonce,
    'to': account_2,
    'value': web3.toWei(1, 'gwei'),
    'gas': 6000000,
    'gasPrice': web3.toWei('0', 'gwei')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to push this transaction on your local blockchain?

I think the issue is `gas:4000`

Please see if using more gas would fix this.

**Example**:

```
tx = {
    'nonce': nonce,
    'to': account_2,
    'value': web3.toWei(1, 'gwei'),
    'gas': 6000000,
    'gasPrice': web3.toWei('0', 'gwei')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two points:

1. Gas price too low, one can not pay zero fee to validate an transaction: `'gasPrice': web3.toWei('0', 'gwei')`
2. You can also let the lib find the gas for you instead of pin it :`gas': 4000,`

try to send this:

```
tx = {
    'nonce': nonce,
    'to': account_2,
    'value': web3.toWei(1, 'gwei'),
    'gas': 0,
    'gasPrice': web3.eth.gas_price
}
gas = web3.eth.estimate_gas(tx)
tx.update({'gas': gas})
```

Comment: i add this , now it is giving diffarent err:  
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 641, in cytoolz.functoolz.c_pipe
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\method_formatters.py", line 580, in raise_solidity_error_on_revert
    raise ContractLogicError('execution reverted')
web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted